# Meshing Music and ASMR

Tags: identify-this-genre

I love interesting music, especially ones that feature ASMR* like qualities. I've wanted to be able to search and find more but I can't figure out the proper genre/term to call that style of music or the right combination of search terms to give me what I'm looking for.

Here are 3 that I've found and enjoy listening to, but I haven't really been able to find anymore and I'm sure there are tons more out there:

[Yosi Horikawa - Letter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBAjW_3ftQo)
[If I Could Live In That Moment - Kaiori Breathe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUEHXdMDUX4)
[Yosi Horikawa - Bubbles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CuJqtNdcJU)

What genre would you call it/how would you go about searching for something like this?

Or does anyone know of any other songs/places where I can find music like this?

I've tried searching "ASMR Music", but the results seem to consist of people whispering and lightly playing an instrument--and that's not what I'm looking for at all if you listen to any of the videos I listed. I've just happened upon the 3 above songs by chance on Spotify. I've tried to do radios based on those songs but it doesn't produce anything like them.

Any suggestions?

*ASMR (Autonomous sensory meridian response): Essentially its sounds that create tingly sensations across the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would describe all three of your examples as ["found object" music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Found_object_(music)).  *Found object* is a style of art pioneered by Picasso and Duchamp, that incorporates random objects (for instance, an old bicycle seat, or, notoriously, a men's room urinal) into a piece of art.  By analogy, found object music uses the sounds of ordinary objects as part of the music, either as instruments, or (as seems to be the case in your examples) as electronic samples.  Here's one of [my own favorite examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CMStzPSidM) of the technique, where the percussion always conjures up for me images of a novelist typewriting a murder mystery.

However, found object music is often [conventional music with non-conventional instruments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WL_LHsVAgSk).  Stylistically, Phillip Siebold has correctly identified your examples as "ambient" music, which is generally wordless (or nearly wordless), non-melodic, and concerned with creating a general atmosphere.

Combining the two terms into a search for "found object ambient" music brought me to [this track](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VldYcJgiYM0), which seems very much in line with your examples.  Also, if you're open to music that's a little less purely atmospheric, the band referenced earlier, [Tunng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunng), has [other tracks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbs87asrNao) that you might like.  Or, for a more mainstream example, the introductory portions of Pink Floyd's ["Welcome to the Machine"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lt-udg9zQSE) and ["Shine on You Crazy Diamond"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8UXircX3VdM) (from *Wish You Were Here*) arguably pioneer versions of the same effect.

Comment: I think this helps me get in the right direction the most, since two of the songs I listed were using more unconventional instruments and noises. I didn't realize there was a term for it and that will definitely help in future searching. Tunng does have some songs that I enjoyed, so thank you for sharing. Great Answer.

Answer (score 3):

The generic name for it is ambient but it is also noise (in a good way).  You could look up some ambient techno as that answers some of what you are looking for.

There are a couple labels out of Germany who specialise in forms of techno that has a high ASMR language about them.  [Stroboscopic Records](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5mKC9PJ0c8) is one of them.  Some people who listen to this and give this stuff the pejorative name "dust house" because of the rasps and scrapes evoke the notion of a dirty record.

Artists to look for in this field:

Lucy

[Kas:st](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoPBoGhfJQk)

[Shackleton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJED5KF50x8)

Comment: I think this is close, the examples I put really weren't techno music though, though I did like the one Lucy song you referenced. The other's really didn't give off the same vibe. I searched around for "dust house" but didn't really find anything attributed to that term, so I'm not sure where you found it, but I like the idea and would like to see more of what it had to offer.

Answer (score 2):

Those are called [Musique Concrète](https://rateyourmusic.com/genre/Musique+concr%C3%A8te/), but with a more modern/musical approach.

[Bernand Parmegiani](https://youtu.be/c_JHjUFfOs8?t=815) is a precursor of the genre.

The group [Matmos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVhlN4wEPR0) is known to combine [IDM](https://rateyourmusic.com/genre/IDM/) with Musique Concrète. The album [Ultimate Care II](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9BGW61_zOA) was made entirely based on sounds of an old washing machine.

You could also like [Glitch](https://rateyourmusic.com/genre/Glitch/). Autechre made some tracks in that style with ASMR leanings: [Rettic Ac](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FE9KlbITTDM) and [elyc6 0nset](https://youtu.be/ugny7uBuspI?t=776).